# Memory leak error while uploading large audio files in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp

I am working on node.js application in which I have to transfer audio files into ftp. I used below code to do that:

```
var readableAudioStream = fs.createReadStream(audiopath);
var writeStream = sftp.createWriteStream('test.wav');
                        // what to do when transfer finishes
writeStream.on('close', function(err) {
          debug("- file transferred");
          sftp.end();
          done(err, Delivered);
      });
       // initiate transfer of file
readableAudioStream.pipe(writeStream);
```

its working fine when I upload 20-22MB audio file but it gives me memory out of bound error when I try to upload 70 MB file.

I try to find solution but none help me.

Comment: What node.js version are you using? What `ssh2` version are you using? Can you post the actual error message? Did you try `sftp.fastPut()` instead?

Comment: node = version 0.10.25 and ssh2 using https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2,.